# Mount a Thunar/Nautilus/Nemo gvfs bookmark using command line

Tags: command-line, nautilus, thunar, nemo, gvfs

I have some bookmark that use smb/sftp through gvfs, how to mount them using command line?

when I click them (mount using mouse click), it shows on `/run/media/myuser/BookmarkName`

So, is there any command to mount an already bookmarked item? for example:

```
gvfs-whatever mount BookmarkName
```

Comment: `gvfs-mount --help`

Comment: gvfs-* commands are deprecated. Seems that it is now all under one command called gio.