# How can I script mounting an SFTP server (suitable for desktop access)?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, sftp, automounting, nautilus

I have a script that opens a remote file in a local desktop application:

```
nohup geany sftp://user@$HOST:22/var/log/nginx/error.log >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

(Note that the hostname is parameterised.)

If I have already clicked on the Nautilus bookmark for that server, the file opens with a message:

```
19:39:31: File /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=hostname,port=22,user=user/var/log/nginx/error.log opened(1).
```

However, if I haven't clicked on the bookmark, the server is not mounted and the file doesn't open, with the following error message.

```
20:43:31: Could not find file 'sftp://user@hostname:22/var/log/nginx/error.log'.
```

How can I script mounting the server so that:

- it opens in Geany
- it appears mounted in Nautilus (as though I had clicked the bookmark)
- making the same call twice has no effect (for example, if I've already clicked on the bookmark or run the script once before)

Comment: Would `sshfs` do better for you?

Comment: @ivanivan I could try that

Comment: also (related but unanwered https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319885 )

Comment: looks like modern gnome would be `gio mount ...`